# HTML entities in Vue filters

Tags: vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and currently going through a tutorial.

I came across the following:

```
Vue.filter('currency', function (value) {
    return '$' + value.toFixed(2);
});
```

I thought I'd change the $ sign to a British pound sign.  Knowing that, just entering the pound sign is not guaranteed to display properly everywhere, I used the html entity instead `&pound;`

But it seems that Vue renders the `&` as `&amp;` giving an end result of `&amp;pound;` which displays as `&pound;` and not as `£`

How do I get round this?

If it helps, here is the html that uses the filter:

```
<span>{{service.price | currency}}</span>
```

Comment: This is quite mind boggling, as I've never had this issue personally. Try doing &amp;pound;

Comment: That just gets converted to `&amp;amp;pound;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string returned by the filter will be treated as plain-text, so if you include `&`, `<`, etc. they'll be escaped to entities.

Rather than trying to use entity escaping inside the filter you can use JavaScript string escaping. e.g.

```js
Vue.filter('currency', function (value) {
    return '\u00a3' + value.toFixed(2);
});
```

Note that `'\u00a3'` will create a single character. You won't see `&pound;` in the DOM but that won't be a problem. It dodges any problems with character encoding in the source file but it is effectively equivalent to writing `'£'`.

Answer (score 1):

for the  £ it should work

```
Vue.filter('currency', function (value) {
    return '£' + value.toFixed(2);
});
```

because vue.js should handle the converting by itself.

EDIT:
If you wanna use other special signs, you can use those 2 methods i found

```js
Vue.filter('currency', function(value) {
  let sign = '&pound;';
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let dom = parser.parseFromString('<!doctype html><body>' + sign, 'text/html');
  return dom.body.textContent + value.toFixed(2)
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    domParser() {
      let sign = '&pound;';
      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let dom = parser.parseFromString('<!doctype html><body>' + sign, 'text/html');
      return dom.body.textContent;
    },
    innerHTML() {
      let sign = '&pound;';
      var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.innerHTML = sign;
      return textArea.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ 25 | currency}}
  <br><br> {{ domParser() }}
  <br><br> {{ innerHTML() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Already tried that, and Vue does not convert it to `&pound;` but leaves it as `£` And what if I wanted another entity that I can't just type.